# Probability of two events occurring simultaneously without replacement

Tags: probability

My colleagues and I are playing a game for Christmas and a question today came up about probabilities. I have tried to determine the answer on my own, but I am stuck. I have read all other forum posts around probability of events occurring without replacement, but I am finding it difficult to adapt those solutions to meet this problem.

**Background/Problem**:
There are 23 people in the department and each person has submitted a childhood photo. These photos were arranged in a random order (1-23) corresponding to a date in December (ex: #3 will happen on December 3rd). Every person’s name was written onto a piece of paper and put into a hat (23 names in total). Every day in December, the photo corresponding to that date is shown and one random name is drawn from the hat. It is that person’s turn to guess who is in the photo.

**Question**:
What is the probability that you will be selected to guess a picture of yourself during this game?

**Note**:

- There is no replacement, so once your photo is shown or your name is drawn from the hat it is out permanently.
- Two simultaneous things need to happen for you to guess yourself: 1) Your picture is being shown that day, 2) Your name was drawn from the hat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have two rows with 23 spaces each. In first row we put pictures and in second row we put names. Now, what we want to happen is that your name is below your picture because this means that both your name and picture were drawn on the same day.

Possible number of combinations is: $23! \cdot 23!$

Now we want to find the number of combinations that suits us - combinations with your name and picture in the same column. We arrange pictures in any possible way giving us 23! of combinations and put your name under your picture. Now, there is 22! combinations of other names around your name. In total, this gives $23!\cdot 22!$ of combinations that suits us.

Probability is given with $\dfrac{\text{number of suitable outcomes}}{\text{number of all possible outcomes}}$, so we have:

$P=\dfrac{23!\cdot 22!}{23!\cdot 23!}=\dfrac{22!}{23!}=\dfrac{1\cdot 2\cdot ...\cdot 22}{1\cdot 2\cdot ...\cdot 23}=\dfrac{1}{23}$

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. I was sure the solution was much more complicated than this, but now I see that I was wrong. Thanks again!

Comment: @Brian no problem ;)

Answer (score 3):

It's just $\frac 1{23}$.

Your name will be drawn from the hat at some point, at which time you will be shown a face.  Symmetry tells us that you are equally likely to be shown any of the available faces.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. I didn't understand why it would be so simple, but MaliMish's response above made it clear to me. I was very much over complicating things.

Comment: Symmetry is a great tool.  If your own picture were, say, more probable than $\frac 1{23}$, then some other picture would have to be less probable.  Which one would that be?